# How do I allow user access to their records only?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am setting up an application hosted on an Azure Website/SQL subscription for a company that would like employees to have usernames (Forms Authentication) to be able to see and do everything in the application related to the company's clients but would also like to have the clients login with usernames and read records that applied only to themselves or their business.

I suspect that a filter or a permission can be set up for each entity that would do this but I am not sure of the best way or how to implement it. This project is in C#.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Beth Massi's video shows how to do this using the Filter event handler.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/jj822934
As long as each entity/table has one or more columns indicating the user (or tenant if multi-tenant) you can add a filter that reflects to all access through LS services.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, look into WebMatrix.WebSecurity, it will have all the basic members such as current logged in user and permission role implemented for you already. After you got those information, you do a check in each of the controller to see if the user has high enough permission to view it if not then return forbidden code.

Let me know if you need more info

Comment: Steve,  Thank you for your response.  I am already a little invested in the VS LS on this project but not that invested.  Would I use Webmatrix with my current LS app, Start a new App in Webmatrix, use Azure/SQL db I created with LS or start that over too.  I have been looking it over and is does look like a good idea. Mark

Comment: @Mark by website..im assuming you are using ASP.NET. if you are then you can just call WebMatrix codes

Answer (score 0):

@Xpert360's response is a good starting point for filtering the data access side of things, but you really need to make sure that you have the data structured the way you need it before you can go down this track.  The key here is literally a KEY value.  You need to create a foreign key between some sort of user reference and each entity set that needs to be restricted in this manner.  There's two basic approaches to doing this.

1. Create your own Users table for this purpose and link that to the aspnet_users table to identify the respective rows (which means accessing the Microsoft.LightSwitch.SecurityData.svc service under an administrative context when inserting new records into your Users table)
2. Include the dbo.aspnet_users table in your data model and create the required foreign keys directly against that table.

You'll need to intercept the Inserting, Updating and Deleting methods for each entity to add a link to the target user record as records are reviewed/assigned/updated.

There are some scenarios where the relationships between records will need to be many-to-many (e.g. in a medical case management system, you might have a whole raft of practitioners needing to access and update a patient's record).  Make sure you implement these relationships using appropriate intersect tables.

Note that the role assignments in VS-LS can be accessed on the server side by using the this.Application.User.HasPermission(Permissions.) construct.  On the client side you can use pretty similar logic in SilverLight screens, but LS-HTML has some javascript objects that you can interrogate for that purpose (which I haven't had an opportunity to use in anger yet).